# Using SQLite-net PCL how can I assign a custom PrimaryKey?

Tags: sql, xamarin, sqlite, android-sqlite

How can I assign a string as a PrimaryKey for a SQLite row? 
Normally, I use this for auto incrementation:

```
public class BaseItem {
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply leave out the "AutoIncrement". This is how we do it in an application by setting in the ctor:

```
public class MySuperAwesomeClass
{
  [PrimaryKey]
  public Guid Key { get; set; }

  public MySuperAwesomeClass()
  {
    Key = Guid.NewGuid();
  }
}
```